# Why do browsers provide an option to disable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

It is just a noob question: why do browsers have a "disable javascript" function?

I am just curious and hunger for learning. Thanks!

Comment: Please see this answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/why-do-people-disable-javascript

Comment: It's so you can test what your site will look like in 2002.

Comment: Disabling javascript might consider the following options: 

Speed & Bandwidth
Usability & Accessibility
Platform Support
Security

Comment: Well answered to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/why-do-people-disable-javascript

Comment: @MichaelHampton - FYI, a minified and GZipped jQuery 2.1 is 29k and will be only downloaded once - after that it will be in the cache.  If you use a popular CDN, it's probably already in the browser cache.  I'm not saying you should use it for one trivial feature, but it certainly doesn't cause 100k of download on each page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're asking why some browsers might have Javascript turned off, it is a user setting in a browser.  The user has the ability to decide whether they want to enable Javascript or not.

Users may choose to disable Javascript for either security or privacy reasons.  It seems less common these days because more and more sites are not fully functional without Javascript enabled.

Comment: I routinely shop at a well known (US) website which works with JavaScript off. If your e-commerce site doesn't, you might not be getting my money.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - nowadays, if you run with Javascript off, you will find some sites that have broken features and many that do not offer full functionality.  From a site designer's point of view, you sacrifice significant usability if you can't check form data client-side, must reload an entire page to update content, can't build a dynamic UI, etc...  I,for one, would not want an internet that lost all that functionality.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would, if it means not having my browser slowed down by all the crappy scripts people use. In practice, NoScript allows me to whitelist the sites that have a legitimate reason for using scripts.

Comment: @immibis - then why don't you run with Javascript turned off?  We're not stopping you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do, but using NoScript, which allows whitelisting. I thought I just said that.

Comment: @immibis - so you've found that you want Javascript turned on for some sites?

Comment: @jfriend00 You phrase that in a biased way. How about I apply the opposite bias: I've found that I want Javascript turned off for almost all sites.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, and quite often when I find such a broken site it's the web designer's fault. A home page that just has a navigation bar, a callout and some other marketing fluff should not need JavaScript simply to appear at all! Yet I see this all the time. CSS, do you speak it?

Comment: agreed on sir @jfriend00 for me, as a user and a developer i dont what to reload entire page just to validate or check the form data. Yes form validation via javascript can be bypass if you disable the javascript on the browser(yes, i need to validate it also from server-side) but it helps the user to prompt instally if the data they been inputting is wrong.

Comment: @immibis - I'm just making a point that an internet without any Javascript is not very practical these days and often makes significant feature or usability sacrifices.  Some people still may want that tradeoff and that's fine, but it is a significant tradeoff.

Comment: The _worst_ offenders, though, are those whose navbars are completely devoid of links in the HTML5, and who add the links in later with JavaScript. How can this _possibly_ be necessary?!

Comment: yes sir,, just forgot to check :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, one reason could be some highly technical users may want full control over how they want their browsers to behave.  Javascript is one part of browser behavior which some users may wish to control.  Thus - it is a question of choice.  Sometimes - some Javascript could be too annoying for some choosy techie users and they may wish to turn it off.

Thus - in addition to security and privacy, it is a choice that browsers offer to end users.  However it is true that nowadays most sites hardly function without JS.  But still there could be those plain old vanilla HTML sites around that may do without any client side scripting.

Regards

Comment: The most well-designed sites function perfectly with _all_ JavaScript disabled, and _good_ web frameworks will provide complete (or nearly complete) support for this, e.g. Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - that's a huge stretch to say.  For one, it's not worth it to spend time designing your web site to offer all functionality without Javascript.  It's such a rare situation these days, that it's a poor use of resources to design for it when you can offer a richer experience by using Javascript.  Try using either GMail or Yahoo Mail without Javascript.  At best, you get a reduced set of features.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I'm not saying that you couldn't design an app without Javascript, but you'd have to make some usability sacrifices to do so and designing both a with and without Javascript site where both offer full features is way, way more work than is worth it.  The major sites I checked out, all offer a reduced functionality site without Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 And that _can_ be an acceptable tradeoff to some (and not others). This is just going to devolve into the graceful degradation vs. progressive enhancement argument again, and I am firmly on the side of progressive enhancement.